# Jquery - клик не на данный элемент вызывает определенный эффект

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$('.menu li a').click(function(event) {
  $('.dropdown_menu').css('display','none');
  $(this).next('.dropdown_menu').css('display','block');
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.menu ul{
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.menu ul li{
  position:relative;
  margin-right:30px;
}
.dropdown_menu{
    position: absolute;
  bottom:-200px;
  left:0%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #000;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
    padding:20px;
}
.dropdown_menu ul{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.dropdown_menu li a{
  color:#fff;
  line-height:1.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Главная</a>
   <div class="dropdown_menu">
    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
       
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     

    </ul>


   </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Комнаты</a>
   <div class="dropdown_menu">
    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     

    </ul>


   </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Услуги</a>
   <div class="dropdown_menu">
    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     

    </ul>


   </div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Больше</a>
   <div class="dropdown_menu">
    <ul>
     
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
     

    </ul>


   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при клике на другой элемент вне dropdown автоматически все закрывалось?

Comment: а что не работает?

Comment: надо сделать так чтобы при клике на внешние элементы dropdown закрывался

Comment: я это понял. я спрашиваю, у вас это не работает? потому как судя по коду должно работать. и тут при выполнении кода блоки скрываются

Comment: при клике на пустое место не срабатывают

Comment: в данном случае пустого места

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не силен в jQuery, но должно помочь

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($('.menu').has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown_menu').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
$('.menu li a').click(function(event) {
  $('.dropdown_menu').css('display', 'none');
  $(this).next('.dropdown_menu').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.dropdown_menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -200px;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #000;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown_menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown_menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Главная</a>
      <div class="dropdown_menu">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>


        </ul>


      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Комнаты</a>
      <div class="dropdown_menu">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>


        </ul>


      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Услуги</a>
      <div class="dropdown_menu">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>


        </ul>


      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Больше</a>
      <div class="dropdown_menu">
        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>


        </ul>


      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: почему у вас $(document).click() добавляется после клика на $('.menu li a') ?

Comment: @user202854, говорю же, с jQuery еще не на "ты", только недавно начал использовать, спасибо за поправку

Comment: хорошо заработало. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

добавьте

```
$(document).click(function(){ 
    $('.dropdown_menu').css('display','none');
})
```

и тут кое что

```
$('.menu li a').click(function(event) {
    $('.dropdown_menu').css('display','none');
    $(this).next('.dropdown_menu').css('display','block');
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.dropdown_menu li a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```